# ng form depended validation on another field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-ng-form

I have a angular form, and I have there two input-fields, one for form and one for email.

I Want to require email OR phone, How do I do it?

I tried to do : `ng-reqired="myForm.phone.$invalid"`, but this doesn't seem to work, once you put in one of the fields (and both became valid), so even after you erase the input, both inputs are still valid, (because once the `phone` became valid, the `email` became valid.

here is my JSfiddle: [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shimonb/yx1orwd2/3/)

I have a short-term solution by doing `ng-required="myForm.email.$viewValue == ''"`, but i'm looking for a better one.

because this will only check if the other field is empty, and I do want to check if it's valid, for example, when the user a non-valid email address, should the phone be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-required="!form.phone && !form.email"` for both text fields.

It means when both model is empty, `required` is set for that input, else unset it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that's more simple then $viewValue == ''.    But still, it'll only check for if the other field is empty, and I want to check if it's "valid".